# How do I remove these characters from my vector of strings

Tags: r, regex, string, text-mining

I need a solution to how I can clean my vector of strings which has characters and symbols,
for example

```
[1]c("hiv3=0", "comdiab=0", "ppl=0")
[2]c("fxet3=1", "hiv3=0", "ppl=0")
[3]c("fxet3=1", "escol4=0", "alcool=0", "tipores3=1")
[4]c("escol4=0", "alcool=0", "ppl=0", "tipores3=1")
```

The intended string will produce

```
[1]"hiv3=0,comdiab=0, ppl=0"
[2]"fxet3=1, hiv3=0, ppl=0"
[3]"fxet3=1, escol4=0, alcool=0, tipores3=1"
[4]"escol4=0, alcool=0, ppl=0, tipores3=1"
```

Any solution is acceptable, though I have tried using the `gsub` function 
Regex solution would be very much acceptable also

Comment: Could you show the `dput` of the example (to avoid any confusion)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the post, it seems to be a `list`of `vector`s.  We can use `paste` to create a single string from the `list` of `vector`s

```
sapply(lst1, paste, collapse=", ")
#[1] "hiv3=0, comdiab=0, ppl=0"         
#[2] "fxet3=1, hiv3=0, ppl=0"     
#[3] "fxet3=1, escol4=0, alcool=0, tipores3=1" 
#[4] "escol4=0, alcool=0, ppl=0, tipores3=1"
```

or otherwise can be modified as

```
sapply(lst1, toString)
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(c("hiv3=0", "comdiab=0", "ppl=0"), c("fxet3=1", "hiv3=0", 
"ppl=0"), c("fxet3=1", "escol4=0", "alcool=0", "tipores3=1"), 
    c("escol4=0", "alcool=0", "ppl=0", "tipores3=1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

tidyverse answer

```
library(tidyverse)

my_strings <- list(c("hiv3=0", "comdiab=0", "ppl=0"),
           c("fxet3=1", "hiv3=0", "ppl=0"),
           c("fxet3=1", "escol4=0", "alcool=0", "tipores3=1"),
           c("escol4=0", "alcool=0", "ppl=0", "tipores3=1"))


map_chr(.x = my_strings, .f = str_c, collapse = " ") 

# [1] "hiv3=0 comdiab=0 ppl=0"              
# [2] "fxet3=1 hiv3=0 ppl=0"                
# [3] "fxet3=1 escol4=0 alcool=0 tipores3=1"
# [4] "escol4=0 alcool=0 ppl=0 tipores3=1"
```